# How to call a stored procedure from iReport?

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, ireport

I'm trying to **call a stored procedure that receives a parameter from the iReport** plugin wizard of Netbeans 6.1, how can I successfully accomplish this task?

*Other technical details are: using MySQL 5.0.51a-17, and iReport designer 1.0.*

Thanks!

Update: I'm voting this question to be closed, since it's from 2008.

Answer (score 2):

Edit the `myreport.jrmxl` file directly:

```
<jasperReport ...>
    ...
    <parameter name="someParam" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <queryString>
       <![CDATA[call myproc($P{someParam})]]>
    </queryString>
    ...
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: ,can u tell me how to take some fields from resultset,return from calling stored procedure ? I am using MS-SQL,but can also use MySQL

Comment: @SagarNikam you should probably just ask a new question, but how many rows and columns are you expecting to be returned from the proc?

Comment: ,I want fixed no of columns but row are not fixed,I know the name of columns

Comment: I know column names,but not number of rows.I am using-->  select * from (call first),where "first" is my stored procedure name

Comment: @SagarNikam I think it's better you ask a new question. This is not the way to do it.